# What is a better translation for 「自分だけバカを見る」?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I have this phrase in my JLPT textbook, as one example of the use of `バカ`:

> 自分{じぶん}だけバカを見{み}る

The translation offered in the book is:

> Waste time and money among others

The English is both awkward and lacks context, so it doesn't help me understand the Japanese at all. The only thing I gain from it is that my own somewhat literal translation is almost certainly wrong. I would translate the Japanese as something like "look only at oneself (to a ridiculous degree)".

Is this some kind of idiomatic usage? What exactly does it mean and why?

Comment: How about that!? http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/174686/m0u/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is used when a person has some **expectation** of what the outcome of the situation will be, but somehow the outcome has been **failed to meet** his/her expectations in such a foolish way.

Using the examples that Tim has provided,

> I thought she is going to show up to meet me, but she didn't and I
>   had waited for almost an hour now. I'm going home. Foolish of me to
>   believe her. バカを見た。
>
> I thought this house was very cheap and rooms are very clean, but I
>   didn't know that it has been 200 years old and underlying structure is
>   very weak. It was foolish of me to buy this house. バカを見た。

Now 自分だけ implies that one has shared some expectations with a number of people, and all of them except you had an expected outcome in the situation.

> At dinner, my boss said that the company is going to be in a good
>   shape in a next few years so I made a plan of moving to a new
>   apartment and buying a new car etc etc, only to find out that he was
>   such a drunk when he said that, and nobody except me believed it nor
>   expected such a salary raise. It was so foolish of me to believe him.
>   自分だけバカをみた。

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It seems I should just throw out the book's translation entirely, and instead, translate `自分だけバカをみた` as "only I looked like a fool". Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes Dave, that sounds right. It makes sense to me.

Comment: "You have only to look at yourself to see a fool". or "If you want to see someone dumb just look in the mirror." Do my attempts accurately reflect the phrase? Idk if I am understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

My dictionary records it as 慣用 (idiomatic). The two examples are:

> 1時間も待ってばかを見た｜I wasted a whole hour waiting for her.
>
> こんな古い家を買ってばかを見た｜I should have known better than to buy such an old house.

I have thought of it as close to もったいない or even "...I was a fool."